# Fairly subtle filter bug between 8 am and 10 pm UTC Dec. 29th

Tags: support, api-v2, filter

This is a public service announcement about a bug that most people probably didn't notice, but might be biting you pretty hard about now.

Between 8 AM and 10 PM UTC December 29th, filters generated by the API were incorrect.  During the same period, filters that were generated before then and passed to the API would be interpreted incorrectly.

What makes this insidious is that no error would be thrown, just dodge data returned.  Primarily, this would manifest as incorrect fields being returned (you meant to get `question_id` and instead got, say, `body`) or an empty response altogether.

Any filters generated and saved during this period will need to be regenerated, filter generated before then should be behaving correctly again.

My apologies for this outage, we're putting some additional checks in place to prevent it from happening again.